# Android startActivity in option menu cause crash application

Tags: android, android-activity, crash, optionmenu

**" I solved the problem by adding the declaration of the activity into Manifest. "**

I want to start an activity when the optionmenu button is pressed.
When i press the button the application crash. 
The application crash when i call "openAbout()" . Thanks to everyone for helping.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0,0,1,R.string.menuAbout);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    default:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
        this.startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }
}

public void openAbout(){
       Intent i = new Intent();
       i.setClass(this, About.class);
       startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Before Starting , plz every time when you have a question , plz add the stack trace so others can understand the type of the problem ,**

**First** , check if your activity is already declared on your manifest file ,

**Second ,** try to change the instanciation of your intent to be like this :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
this.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: i.setClass(this, About.class); is valid, so no need of "Second"

Comment: Thanks ! i'm very sorry for not adding "Stack trace". I solved the problem by adding the activity into the manifest. sorry again and thanks !!